# swift 5 Почему появляется ошибка(на изображении)

Tags: swift, xcode

import UIKit

private let reuseIdentifier = "Cell"

class FleshCollectionViewController: UICollectionViewController {

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations
    // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = false

    // Register cell classes
    self.collectionView!.register(UICollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

/*
// MARK: - Navigation

// In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    // Get the new view controller using [segue destinationViewController].
    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
}
*/

// MARK: UICollectionViewDataSource

override func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
    return 0
}


override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of items
    return 0
}

override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath)

    // Configure the cell

    return cell
}

// MARK: UICollectionViewDelegate

/*
// Uncomment this method to specify if the specified item should be highlighted during tracking
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, shouldHighlightItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
    return true
}
*/

/*
// Uncomment this method to specify if the specified item should be selected
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, shouldSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
    return true
}
*/

/*
// Uncomment these methods to specify if an action menu should be displayed for the specified item, and react to actions performed on the item
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, shouldShowMenuForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
    return false
}

override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, canPerformAction action: Selector, forItemAt indexPath: IndexPath, withSender sender: Any?) -> Bool {
    return false
}

override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, performAction action: Selector, forItemAt indexPath: IndexPath, withSender sender: Any?) {

}
*/
```

}[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Арсений, Вам Xcode пишет, что не может найти контроллер, с которого ему стартовать программу. Вы случайно или специально убрали галочку об этом.
Вам нужно нажать на заголовок контроллера и включите показанную на скрине галочку "Is Initial View Controller". При этом у контроллера слева должна появиться стрелочка (которой у вас сейчас нет), показывающая, что это стартовый контроллер для приложения.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

P.S. Пока писал ответ, понял, что вы наверно просто создали новый, этот ваш текущий вью контроллер, а тот, который был по умолчанию, удалили (вместе со "стрелкой"). Скорее всего так и было :)